# AngularJS + Use of JavaScript Constant + Unable to View on UI

Tags: json, angularjs, constants

In AngularJs app, I am trying to use constant for rendering few thing like YES or NO using Constant. But unable to implement it.

**Snippet:-**

/* constant.js File*/

```
/*
    Constant For Boolean
*/
var CONSTANT_TRUE  = "True"
var CONSTANT_FALSE = "False"
var CONSTANT_YES   = "Yes"
var CONSTANT_NO    = "No"
```

**AngularJs Snippet:-**

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Scholarship</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>
    <td>{{student.age}}</td>
    <td>{{student.is_student == true ? CONSTANT_YES : CONSTANT_NO}}</td>
    <td>{{student.scholarship == "yes" ? CONSTANT_YES : CONSTANT_NO}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JSON Output**

> { id: 1, name: "John", age: 20, is_student: true, scholarship: "no" }

**On UI - Browser Inspect Eleement**

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Scholarship</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place those constant in controller `$scope` so that it can get accessible on HTML.

If this are the constant value which are hardly going to change, then I will prefer you create an angular `constant` which is kind of service.

**Constant**

```
app.constant('myConstants', {
    CONSTANT_TRUE : "True",
    CONSTANT_FALSE : "False",
    CONSTANT_YES : "Yes",
    CONSTANT_NO : "No"
})
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myConstants){
    //other awesome code here
    $scope.myConstants = myConstants; //binded to the scope to get access to constant on HTML.

})
```

**Edit**

If you don't wanted to expose constant inside the `$scope` then I'd suggest you to use `myConstants` directly inside the controller. At that time while binding data to view you need to call the method & that method will perform an operation and it will return data.

**Markup**

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
    <th>Student</th>
    <th>Scholarship</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>
    <td>{{student.age}}</td>
    <td>{{isStudent(student)}}</td>
    <td>{{isScholarship(student)}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Controlle**

```
$scope.isStudent = function (){
    return student.is_student ? myConstants.CONSTANT_YES : myConstants.CONSTANT_NO;
};

$scope.isStudent = function (){
    return student.scholarship == "yes" ? myConstants.CONSTANT_YES : myConstants.CONSTANT_NO;
};
```

Comment: PlusOne - Excellent One. I am trying your suggestion.